# How to stop ui-router from reloading resolve when params change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an app with a base app ui router state...

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
  navigationTitleKey : 'app',
  abstract: true,
  url: '/?{param}',
  views: obj
});
```

And then a `child` and `grand-child` state...

```
$stateProvider.state('app.wizardchild', {
  parent: 'app',
  url: '/wizard',
  resolve: {
     wizard: ['wizard',function(wizard) {
      return new wizard();
    }],
  },

 $stateProvider.state('app.wizardgrandchild', {
      parent: 'app.wizardchild'
   }
```

When I do...

`$state.go('app.wizardgrandchild')` from `app.wizardchild`

It works as expected and the wizard has only been resolved once.

But when I do `$state.go('app.wizardgrandchild', {param:'blah'})` from `app.wizardchild`

It re-runs the resolve block meaning that on the `grand-child` state has a new copy of wizard. But I don't want that to happen I want it to be the same and not have another copy created. Is there any way to turn off this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try to register `wizard` as service (not factory). Since all Angular services are singletons it should solve your problem. Now every time you create new instance of wizard using `new` - if you use service Angular will automatically create an instance and inject it every time it's required (every time the same instance will be injected)

Answer (score 0):

Your `param` is declared on the `app` state.  When a state's parameter changes, it is reloaded using the new parameter value.  When a state reloads, all its children also reload.

If you can move the parameter declaration to the grandchild state, that should solve the problem.

Alternatively, you can keep `param` on the app state and [mark it as `dynamic`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/params.paramdeclaration.html#dynamic).  Dynamic parameters will not cause the state to reload.

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
  navigationTitleKey : 'app',
  abstract: true,
  url: '/?{param}',
  params: { param: { dynamic: true } },
  views: obj
});
```

If you're using ui-router legacy  (0.x), [there is `reloadOnSearch`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.4.2/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) which is similar, but can be buggy.

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
  navigationTitleKey : 'app',
  abstract: true,
  url: '/?{param}',
  reloadOnSearch: false,
  views: obj
});
```